# where to find/buy this part?

Tags: connector, components

I'm trying to find these two metal connector parts to make a bulb socket on my device's :

[image]

It's a common part in bulb sockets and I don't know why I can't find them on the internet.

How can I find and buy these parts and parts like this ?

Comment: If you were a Chinese socket company 1 cent bulk order 10k MOQ, a DIY engineer says drill out rivet, free from old socket, but DIY might not be in your culture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're brass metal stamping parts. You can easily find a Chinese manufacturer that will supply them, as well as others, though some may want tooling charges so you may wish to look for one that already has the tooling on hand (and will maintain it at no cost to you).

The center contact is a simple stamping (it could be made by a couple of operations or in a [progressive die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_stamping)). The socket part is formed by [deep drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_drawing#:%7E:text=Deep%20drawing%20is%20a%20sheet,drawn%20part%20exceeds%20its%20diameter.).

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/gbWEERM.png

Answer (score 4):

You won't find them, because the bulb sockets are mass produced for such a low price and parts aren't replaceable.  If you want those parts, then buy another socket.

Comment: no, I dont need them for my socket, I need them for my own device production